# Calculate time difference between two times using ISO 8601

Tags: python, time, iso8601

I have two times for example:

`2020-04-06T15:00:07Z`
`2021-07-28T19:18:02+0000`

I am wondering how I can get the desired output of `1 year ago` or `2 hours ago`

I tried converting the times to seconds then subtracting that and converting the time to the desired output but I just can't find the code in the documentation that allows for that.

Comment: _"I just can't find the code in the documentation that allows for that"_: What is "that"? Parsing the strings into datetime objects? Converting to seconds? Subtracting? Converting back to hours/days/years? Please [edit] your question to include your attempt as a [mre], and ask a _specific_ question about the issue you ran into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

datetime_1 = parse('2020-04-06T15:00:07Z')
datetime_2 = parse('2021-07-28T19:18:02+00:00')

delta = relativedelta(datetime_2, datetime_1)

print(f"{delta.years} year {delta.months} months {delta.days} days {delta.hours} hours {delta.hours} minutes ago")

# 1 year 3 months 22 days 4 hours 4 minutes ago
```